# Sharepoint API - List all files in a folder

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to list all files in the folder 'Brown Boronia' but get a File Not found message. I think it has someting to do with the folder url I'm using but could be wrong. trying api requests such as below

..../sites/PBRDocumentStoreTest/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Pre-lodgement Application/Brown Boronia')?$expand=Files

Below is how the structure looks in the SharePoint UI. Any ideas on how I can retrieve a list of the files in this folder would be appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research and testing, please try to use the following Rest API to list all files in the folder 'Brown Boronia':

```
https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/zellatest/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/zellatest/Prelodgement%20Application/Brown%20Boronia')
```

Hope it can help you. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it is very likely that your library has been renamed, causing you to see different values in the name and URL, just like the shared document that comes with SharePoint.
[image]

You can check whether the values of these two parts are equal, if not, please use the value in the URL in the Rest API.